# Inequality involving side lengths of a triangle

Tags: inequality, triangles

If $a,b,c$ are sides of a triangle prove that $$a^4+b^4+c^4<2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)$$

Answer (score 2):

your inequality is equivalent to $$- \left( c+a+b \right)  \left( -c+a+b \right)  \left( a-b-c \right) 
 \left( -b+c+a \right) 
>0$$
this is true since we have that $$a,b,c$$ are sides of a triangle.